# Can I make tagpdf work with the caption, footmisc and microtype packages?

Tags: accessibility, tagpdf

I have a document that needs to be meet accessibility requirements (Section 508 compliance in the U.S.). I thought I could get there with auto-tagging in Adobe and placing alt-text by doing `\pdftooltip{\includegraphics{someimage.png}}{This is an image}`. However, it is looking like the 508 people at my agency aren't entirely satisfied with that solution for alt-text.

I've tried using the new `\DocumentMetadata` command that loads the tagpdf package, and while it correctly tags the document and adds alt text using the "alt" tag in `\includegraphics`, it also seems to clash with other packages that I need to match my organization's report template. Specifically it seems to clash with caption and with footmisc, and cancels the formatting set by those packages. I also get an warning from microtype, though I'm not sure if that's actually causing problems.

Here's a MWE:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III}
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{uppercase}{\MakeUppercase{#1}} % Define an uppercase option for main caption text
\captionsetup{font={sf,small},
                textformat=uppercase} % Main text should be uppercase

\usepackage[hang,ragged]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Caption}

\includegraphics[alt={some example image}]{cfpb-logo.jpg}
\end{figure}
Test\footnote{test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test}
\end{document}
```

Commenting out the first line it compiles fine, with the caption in block caps, and the footnote having a hanging indent. With `\DocumentMetadata` the font reverts to normal, the hanging indent goes away, and I get an error "A <box> was supposed to be here."

Are there any ad hoc fixes possible here, or is this a case where I just need to wait for development to proceed on the LaTeX pdf tagging project (a huge, huge thanks to those developers, by the way!).

If relevant to answers, I'd like to incorporate any fix into the custom class I developed (built on top of the default report class) to mimic my organization's Word template--so if e.g. the order in which packages are loaded becomes relevant, addressing where to load things in my class would be helpful.

Comment: well for footmisc there is an open issue https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/issues/12. Add a comment and your example there to put a bit pressure on the issue. The caption package is more problematic. Currently caption tagging is quite hard coded and we probably would need help from the caption maintainer.